# Recomendación de alternativas para gestión masiva de información a través de API

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, azure

Tengo una API RESTful con Secure Token en Node.JS, la cual se encuentra montada en un Docker Node-Slim y se encuentra en producción en Microsoft Azure App Services.

La API trabaja con ‘express’, ‘jwt’ y se encuentra conectado a una base de datos SQL Server utilizando ‘mssql’, los procesos de actualización, eliminación, selección e inserción (CRUD) funcionan correctamente.
Sin embargo, tenemos dentro de la misma API funciones de “Gestión masiva de información” (POST), funciones que se encargan de realizar el ingreso masivo de información a través de un arreglo en JSON, esta función espera a que finalice la ejecución para dar respuesta al comando POST.
Respecto a estas funciones de “Gestión masiva de información” tenemos los siguientes problemas:

- Como estándar, las peticiones HTTP no deben tomar tanto tiempo, Azure
  App Services tiene un limite de 230 segundos de ejecución, por lo que
  estamos limitados a este tiempo y debido a esto enviamos pequeños
  “lotes” de información en vez de una única ejecución.
- Al momento en que se realiza la ejecución de forma masiva durante el
  tiempo en que se esta ejecutando esta operación el tiempo de las
  demás peticiones de la API se incrementa, independiente del tipo de
  petición CRUD, Esto hace que muchas peticiones que se realizan en el
  sistema respondan TimeOut.

Debido a esto, el problema que tenemos actualmente obedece a la “Gestión masiva de información” (POST) y como manejar estos eventos para que el sistema no tenga un tiempo de demora excedido, por el momento, veo las siguientes alternativas:

- Implementación de “Tareas” de forma que al recibir la petición masiva
  (POST), la API entregué un identificador de forma inmediata al POST,
  con el cual podrá obtener un detalle del estado del proceso a través
  de una petición GET. De esta forma la petición se continuará
  ejecutando en background pero sin alterar los tiempos de respuesta.
- Separación de la API en microservicios, de forma que cada componente
  de la aplicación trabaje de forma independiente por lo que cada
  componente de ejecución no alteraría los tiempos entre sí.

Finalmente, por el momento, no estamos seguros de si el problema ocurre en el bucle de tareas de Node (En la pila de ejecución o callback) o bien debido a que al dejar la petición POST “colgada” esta interfiera con el resto de las peticiones.

Comment: A que te refieres con masiva y que SQL Server manejan ya que como comentas si lo mandan como JSON SQL Server 2016 y posteriores ya permite el manejo de este tipo y podrian dejarle la carga al motor

Comment: Con "Gestión Masiva" me refiero a modo de ejemplo si un "POST" normal en un CRUD realiza una Inserción de un registro (A través de un objeto JSON) en base de datos, con el "POST" de la "Gestión Masiva" se realizan múltiples ingresos en base de datos (Registros), a través de un arreglo de objetos JSON.

Comment: Y que version de SQL Server tienes

Comment: Y un worker asincronico que conteste en lugar de tener que preguntar cada 2 segundos con un get? y primero, yo trataria de ver donde esta el cuello de botella del lado del servidor. Mas alla de lo interesante, la pregunta carece de una pregunta en si. Esto mas bien a desarrollar un monton de respuestas con ideas y tips, pero ninguna que pueda ser "correcta". Es una pregunta basada en opiniones...